# Hello, I need help in understanding the grammatical structure of this sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence, subjects, objects

I need help in understanding the grammatical structure of this sentence.  Could anyone break it down?  Thank you very much!!

"Scattered among the leaves crawl creatures called Zeepers that are half insect, half animal".

Comment: The word order is unusual, but may be good. What puzzles you?

Comment: A little structural change may make it sound easy: Scattered among the leaves, creatures called Zeepers that are half insect, half animal, crawl.

Comment: @RamPillai The verb is too far from the subject.

Comment: @LPH - Well, that is why the original sentence was written as it was - to avoid this problem. The comment by Ram Pillai breaks the original down, as was asked for.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica This is the normal order  but still, it is not easier to read; the verb "crawl" gives the reader  the impression of a dangling element at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment by @Ram Pillai.

What may be puzzling to you is the verb-subject inversion. Usually in a statement in English, we would say, "creatures crawl", not "crawl creatures". In everyday English, this sentence would be easier to understand if it were

*Scattered among the leaves, **we can see** creatures (called Zeepers) that are half insect, half animal.*

or

*Scattered among the leaves, **are** creatures (called Zeepers), that are half insect, half animal.*

The author uses what is called [poetic licence](https://www.britannica.com/art/poetic-license), to give the verb "crawl" a double purpose. (1) it tells us that the creatures exist, i.e. they "are" and (2) it tells us that they crawl.

The style of the sentence is somewhat poetic and cleverly written.

Here's a paraphrase in more prosaic language

*Scattered among the leaves, creatures crawl. They are called Zeepers and are half insect, half animal.*

or

*Creatures called Zeepers (that are half insect, half animal) crawl among the leaves. They are scattered among the leaves.*

As you can see, the paraphrases do not flow as well as the original.

Comment: In your last sentence, as there is a "support" for "crawl" (adjunct), a non defining clause could be used, the verb does not appear to be "isolated" any more: " Creatures called Zeepers, that are half insect, half animal, crawl among the leaves. They are scattered among the leaves.".

Comment: @LPH - I agree.